# Android, SQLite unrecognized token

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I get an unrecognized token exception when I try to delete from my database.
I have tried to include my strings in `''` instead of `""`, I have tried storing the values in dedicated string variables and nothing.

I just don't know what to do, here is the code as it is currently:

```
public void deleteCrime(Crime crime) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(crime);

    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,
            values.getAsString(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID) + "= ?",
            new String[]{crime.getId().toString()});

}
```

I have tried it this way too:

```
public void deleteCrime(Crime crime) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(crime);

    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,
            values.getAsString(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID) + "= " + crime.getId().toString(),
            null);

}
```

And this:

```
 public void deleteCrime(Crime crime) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(crime);

    String databaseId = values.getAsString(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID);
    String crimeId = crime.getId().toString();

    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,
            databaseId + "= ?",
            new String[]{crimeId});

}
```

And:

```
public void deleteCrime(Crime crime) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(crime);

    String databaseId = values.getAsString(CrimeTable.Cols.UUID);
    String crimeId = crime.getId().toString();

    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,
            databaseId + "= " + crimeId,
            null);

}
```

And all the combinations and permutations of applying `''` and `" "` to the strings...
Even if I don't parse them into strings and use `''` or `""` on them, I always get the same error (from the first 4 codes in this post):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ricardo.criminalintent, PID: 27841
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "46cf" (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM crimes WHERE fe950f06-dd38-46cf-898e-f4a7f7f27dab = fe950f06-dd38-46cf-898e-f4a7f7f27dab
```

And if I try another row in my database:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ricardo.criminalintent, PID: 28258
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: b09902bc (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM crimes WHERE b09902bc-0829-4989-8395-ed24dc397a85 = b09902bc-0829-4989-8395-ed24dc397a85
```

And...

```
public void deleteCrime(Crime crime) {
    mDatabase.delete(CrimeTable.NAME,
            CrimeTable.Cols.UUID + "=? ",
            new String[]{crime.getId().toString()});

}
```

Or (from the last code in this post, the one with the And...):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ricardo.criminalintent, PID: 3418
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "46cf" (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM crimes WHERE uuid= fe950f06-dd38-46cf-898e-f4a7f7f27dab
```

I don't know what else to do... I'm desperate, please help me!

Comment: Show which error belongs to which code.

Comment: I edited it CL, hope it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, instead:

```
public void deleteCrime(Crime crime)
{
    mDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM crimes WHERE uuid = ?", new String([] {crime.getId()}));
}
```

Comment: Hi Rotwang, it worked like a charm! I guess sometimes writing the DELETE FROM instead of using .delete is the way to go. Would you care explaining why this is?

Comment: Both methods are valid. I prefer the `execSQL()` way, since it gives me more flexibility. And I know it better. Maybe there's simply something wrong in your syntax. The only counter-indication is that it won't return the number of the affected rows.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a syntax error, I've been trying to correct that but can't find the right way... Anyway, I believe using `execSQL()` might be the way to go in general. Thanks a lot @Rotwang!